# find query syntax misconception

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to nodejs and mongodb . Below I am trying to search for a certain account based on username and password . If true console their details else redirect to ('/main') route . There is nothing wrong with routes . I am using mlabs where project1 is the name of my collections . I think everything is going wrong in my find query but I can't figure out what .

```
Schema :-
{
   "_id": "id",
   "UserName": "UserName",
   "Password": "Password"
}
```

***app.js***

```
 MongoClient.connect(url , function(err,db){
    if (err) return;

        app.post('/login' , urlencoder , function(req,res){     
            var user = { 
                UserName : req.body.UserName ,
                Password : req.body.Password
            };
            db.collection('project1').find({user}).forEach(function(pes){   
                    if(true)
                    {
                       console.log(pes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       res.redirect('/main');
                    }
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: `.find(user)`. It's already an object. You're making it `.find({ "user": user })` which is just horribly wrong. Read [Property Definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) and realize what the syntax actually does.

Comment: can you post your `project1` schema

Comment: Note that `if (true)` is always true and you'll never redirect to /main.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in your logic

1. You should  try to connect to mongodb before actually starting the server something like this

   ```
   let globalDb;
   MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
      if(!err) {
         globalDb = db;
         app.listen(3000, () => {
           console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
         });
      }
   })
   ```
2. Your find query should not is passing  nested user fields {user} instead it should be passing

   ```
   app.post('/login' , urlencoder , function(req,res){     
       var user = { 
           UserName : req.body.UserName ,
           Password : req.body.Password
       };

       globalDb.collection('project1').find(user)(function(err,data){                       
            if(data) {
                  // user exist
                  // do something 
            }
       });
   });
   ```